# Javascript read JSON from url

Tags: javascript, php, json

So I'm trying to list out information about users in my database, and with PHP creating a json_encoding for each user.

I have a PHP file that have this code:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ");
$userinfo = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
    $userinfo[] = $row;    


foreach ($userinfo as $user) {
    echo  json_encode(array('id' => $user['id']));
}
```

This gives me this output:

```
{"id":"518536076"}{"id":"511953404"}{"id":"557076722"} etc..
```

Then I want to read this information with my Javascript file by using:

```
$.ajax({ 
   type: "POST", 
   url: "http://url to php file.php",
   datatype: 'json',
   success: function(data){
      var parsed_data = $.parseJSON(data);
      var nTotal = parsed_data.id;
      console.log(nTotal);
   }
});
```

But this does not work in my favor, Im just getting

```
JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data
```

Any idea of what I need to fix on to make this work?

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: you dont call json_encode multiple times that will give you invalid json text, just call `json_encode($userinfo);` and it will do the whole array. Also when providing JQuery's ajax method with `dataType:'json'` it will automatically parse it, no need to parse it yourself.

Comment: Is that Javascript exactly as it appears? Because there's a missing quote at the end of the url.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks :) No, I must have forgot when I removed my url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is on the back end side:

You should replace your last foreach with this:

```
$output = array();
foreach ($userinfo as $user) {
    $output[] = array('id' => $user['id']);
}

header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode( $output ),
```